# What is one word for only one option?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expression for a choice which isn't really one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80876/expression-for-a-choice-which-isnt-really-one)

What is one word for "only one option"?
I am curious because I have to have an antonym for choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link http://thesaurus.com/browse/no+choice.

There are a few possibilities: a *requirement, necessity, must, precondition, prerequisite, stipulation*. It all depends upon the context and whether it works in the specific sentence you're writing.

Comment: This question is not an **_exact_** duplicate. It asks for **one word, a single term, not for a multiword phrase** like _Hobson's choice_ or _Catch 22_ or _Six of one and half a dozen of the other_. How can 5 native speakers with so many reputation points read both questions and then use the semantically inaccurate term _exact duplicate_ to describe what are merely heterozygous (fraternal) and not homozygous (identical) twins?